# MVC data annotations and templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In this MVC scaffold code I understand a template is being used and I can define my own templates.
Also, the data annotations on the object sent to the view are being taken into account.

But what is modelItem?

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReferenceNum)
        </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

`modelitem` is an unuses background variable.

`DisplayFor` expects a method that receives a single parameter.
The implementation of that method is, de-facto, the right side of the lambda expression: `item.[SOMETHING]`.
It just happens that `item.[SOMETHING]` totally ignores `modelitem`.
Replacing `modelitem` with `item` would, of course, result in a compilation error, because `item` belongs to `Model`, and it's not the object that was created when calling the anonymous method `{ item.[SOMETHING] }`.

That's why `modelitem` can be practically any name that doesn't already exist in the symbols table (i.e. that the compiler doesn't already have definition for).

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the parameter for Html.DisplayFor is a lambda-expression: given a modelItem, you refer to the modelItem.ReferenceNum property. The modelItem is of the same type as Model.

Remark: it should read modelItem => modelItem.ReferenceNum. Or otherwise: item => item.ReferenceNum.

Answer (score 1):

Short awnser is that `Model` and the argument `modelitem` to the lambda sent to DisplayFor is the same object.

`Html` in this case is a property of the type [HtmlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492619.aspx) on the view class. T in this case is the type of your view state that you passed to the view.

The view exposes your viewstate in its `Model` property as you've noted. It has also instanciated its `Html` property with a HtmlHelper with the same value, so when you use the `Html` property, it actually passes the same value in again to the lambda you provide.

The name modelItem here is just a name for your lambda, it could be anything.